# htaccess RewriteRule using slash as get params: can't access other files in the folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple user system in my site. The URL works like this: /profile/user?id=*user_id*

I wanted to do something like /profile/user/*user_id* instead, and I found the following code to use in htaccess.

`RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?id=$1 [L]`

The code does work as intended, but after doing that I found out that **I can't access any other file inside of the profile directory besides the index file**. All of them return a 404 error.
There's a couple more of important pages in there, so I would need to access them. I can't access user.php without an ID either, but that's not my main concern, even though I would also like to access it if possible.

I'm not really used to use RewriteRule, so I'm not really sure what's going on here. What can I do?

---

**EDIT:** I was asked to give more info, here we go.

The profile folder full route is /en/profile

Structure of the profile folder:

> profile/settings.php `(directory index)`
>   profile/user.php
>   profile/change_avatar.php
>   profile/change_avatar_upload.php
>   profile/change_email.php
>   profile/change_password.php
>   profile/custom_utgen_characters.php
>   profile/custom_utgen_character_editor.php
>   profile/reset_password.php

Other lines in the htaccess file:
`DirectoryIndex settings.php`

htaccess file in the root folder of the website:
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`

This is all the relevant option I could get, I hope it helps.

Comment: Please give examples of what requests exactly aren’t working. Are you requesting them with the .php extension, or without? (Asking because you seem to deliberately rewrite anything to the index.php, if a matching file with the suffix `.php` exists.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your rewrite rule and directory structure and had no problems to access files in the profile directory. Can you provide more information like the complete `.htaccess` file and the directory structure laying under `profile`?

---

**EDIT:** The .htaccess in your profile folder overwrites the .htaccess in your root folder. To prevent this, you have to add the line

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

to the .htaccess file in the profile folder.

Comment: Of course! I edited the post to add as much relevant info as I could.

Comment: It worked after I added the inherit line! I had no idea rewrite rules weren't inherited by default. Everything seems to be working wonderfully, thank you so much for your help!